# Difference between declaration of variable with extern and without it

Tags: c, linker, extern

`1.h`

```
extern int a;
```

`1.c`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "1.h"

int main(){ 
 printf("%d\n", a);
 return 0;
}
```

`2.c`

```
#include "1.h"

int a = 6;
```

This compiles and runs just fine (gcc 1.c 2.c) if you remove `extern` from `1.h` and prints `6`. 
I know that removing it might cause `a` to be defined in every translation unit (object file), but what is the problem? doesn't the linker just git rid of it when linking since it compiles with no errors?

Comment: If you remove `extern`, your `a` in `1.c` will be uninitialized and the `printf` will invoke undefined behavior.

Comment: but isn't linked to the correct value during linking? is there a gcc rule regarding this?

Comment: Actually you should be getting multiple definitions error when linking... unless I am missing something here.

Comment: No I don't get any errors.

Comment: Hm. Maybe no error because the `2.c` is completely optimized out. But there is definitely an undefined behavior, because when I try to reproduce it, it prints `0` for me.

Comment: That makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

This technique does not conform to the letter of the C standard and the
'one definition rule' — it is officially undefined behaviour:

> **[J.2 Undefined behavior](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#J.2)**
>
> An identifier with external linkage is used, but in the program there
> does not exist exactly one external definition for the identifier, or
> the identifier is not used and there exist multiple external
> definitions for the identifier (6.9).
>
> **[§6.9 External definitions ¶5](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.9p5)**
>
> An *external definition* is an external declaration that is also a
> definition of a function (other than an inline definition) or an
> object.
> If an identifier declared with external linkage is used in an
> expression (other than as part of the operand of a `sizeof` or
> `_Alignof` operator whose result is an integer constant), somewhere in
> the entire program there shall be exactly one external definition for
> the identifier; otherwise, there shall be no more than
> one.<sup>161)</sup>
>
> <sup>161)</sup> Thus, if an identifier declared with external linkage
> is not used in an expression, there need be no external definition for
> it.

more here:
[How do I use extern to share variables between source files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433204/how-do-i-use-extern-to-share-variables-between-source-files)